# Javax Validation

Tags: spring, validation

I'm trying to use Javax Validation with Spring. When I run my application, I get this strange error message

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:43)
    javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:161)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I have hibernate-validator-4.0.2 GA.jar in my classpath which seems to have the missing class. I also use jdk 6. What is going wrong? I've googled, but no answer is found.

Answer (score 13):

The stack trace shows that the Hibernate Validator and `javax.validation` API JARs are both on your classpath OK, so the problem lies elsewhere.

The source code for `ConfigurationImpl` shows that it has a dependency on SLF4J.

I'm guessing that's not your classpath?

Comment: Yes I have validation-api 1.0.0 GA

Comment: SLF4J, exactly. That must be it.

Comment: I have slf4j, slf4j.helpers and slf4j.spi. But I have added these jars directly from an other project's lib folder. Could it have something to do with this problem?

Comment: @mjgirl: Sounds suspicious, yes. Try adding them directly, see what happens.

Comment: Just adding to mention that mjgirl mentions in a separate answer that it was mismatching slf4j jar files, so this answer is very close to being correct.

Answer (score 9):

I solved it adding the following to the POM in a Maven project:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

You can also check the [official reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3143).

Answer (score 3):

Jar- hibernate-validator4.3.1 final.jar
file- HibernetValidator.java 
line 41-

```
 public Configuration<?> createGenericConfiguration(BootstrapState state) 
 {
    return new ConfigurationImpl(state);
 }
```

the ConfigurationImpl class has a static initializer block

```
static
 {
     Version.touch();
     log = LoggerFactory.make();
  }
```

The LogFactory class refreences org.jboss.logging.Logger.

So add jboss-logging-3.2.0.Final.jar to the dependencies and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the hibernate-validator-4.0.2 GA.jar is deployed in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. My slf4j jar versions were not matching together, aswell as I had the undirect libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I had two version of `slf4j-api` in my classpath - `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` as well as `slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar`. I removed the latter and that solved my issue with

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl".
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a missing "jboss-logging" jar

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.Solved it by adding following dependency, eventhough not using hibernate as such.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have clashing versions of `hibernate-validator` and `validation-api`. You can read more about it in this issue:

[JPA 2.0 : Exception to use javax.validation.* package in JPA 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730329/jpa-2-0-exception-to-use-javax-validation-package-in-jpa-2-0)

If you want to use the most recent `hibernate-validator` version, then you should remove the `validation-api` dependency and just add the following dependency for `hibernate-validator`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```