# JPA 2.0 : Exception to use javax.validation.* package in JPA 2.0

Tags: hibernate, validation, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, javabeans

when i try to using bean validation with JPA using hibernate , the follwoing exception will occur :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Chapter11] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at example.test.Test.main(Test.java:18)

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:306)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
... 15 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 20 more
```

i am new to use validation package and i have not knowledge of JAVA EE beans . how to use this validation package with jpa entity following is my code :

```
 public class Employee implements Serializable , EmployeeDetail{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
@NotNull
private String name;
    ____________________

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Chapter11");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction etr = em.getTransaction();

    etr.begin();
            ------------------

        FullTimeEmployee flEmp = new FullTimeEmployee();
        flEmp.setName("Harmeet Singh");
        flEmp.setPension(56000);
        flEmp.setSalary(100000);

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        validator.validate(flEmp, Employee.class);

        em.persist(flEmp);
    etr.commit();
```

Comment: Which app server are you using in which version?

Comment: there is no application server using , implement JPA with corejava

Comment: from which jar are you getting the annotations (e.g. @NotNull) from? Do you have a jsr 303 implementation (e.g. Hibernate Validator) on your classpath?

Comment: i have 2 jar file on my class path 1. `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` and 2. `hibernate-validator-5.0.0.Alpha2.jar` .

Comment: Hibernate Validator 5 does implement bean-validation 1.1 (source http://planet.jboss.org/post/first_alpha_release_of_hibernate_validator_5). So these jars do not fit together. You need hibernate validtor 4

Answer (score 109):

As @Korgen mentioned in comments *hibernate-validator-5.x.x* isn't compatible with *validation-api-1.0.x*. This is because of moving to new specification JSR-303 -> JSR-349.

There are two ways to solve this issue:

**1.** Downgrade hibernate validator version (which is implements JSR-303):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**2.** If you don't want to move back from hibernate validator 5 to hibernate validator 4 another solution is to upgrade javax.validation to higher version (which is describe JSR-349):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In case of maven build hibernate validator 5 already has dependency validation-api 1.1.0.Final. No need to add it explicitly.

Comment: hibernate-validator 4.3.2.Final is too comptatible

Answer (score 21):

For those who got error `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/valueextraction/ValueExtractorDeclarationException` and their validation-api was already `javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final`

The fix was to upgrade from `javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final` to `javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final`.