# GWT Requestfactory issue with Maven + IntelliJ

Tags: maven, gwt, intellij-idea, requestfactory

I am working on a webapp project using GWT 2.5.1 and the requestfactory with a maven config. Actually, I began the project out of maven as a standalone project in eclipse and it still works fine.

But for integration purpose I had to integrate the project as a maven module and to use IntelliJ IDE. And now, when I launch the project on dev mode it works, but as soon as I use the requestfactory I get an Error500. I have found many topic on this subject but I still can not fix it.

I guess this error is either related to annotating processing or to pom.xml config.

About annotationg processing with gwt requestfactory-apt.jar configuration, I can not get the rep .apt_generated with my new configuration with maven in IntelliJ like I did in eclipse and I don't understand why.

Here is my maven config pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>toolkit2</artifactId>
    <groupId>somepackage</groupId>
    <version>v2-maven-alpha</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>docentryeditor</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging> 
<name>doc-entry-editor</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gwt-maven</id>
        <url>http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<!--  include pluginRepository and repository for GWT-Maven -->
<pluginrepositories>
    <pluginrepository>
        <id>gwt-maven-plugins</id>
        <url>http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo/</url>
    </pluginrepository>
</pluginrepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <classifier>deps</classifier>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
        <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
        <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-20050927.133100</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>docentryeditor</finalName>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <!--<outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>-->
    <plugins>
        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin
                documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>XDS-MetadataEditor.html</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- RequestFactory Validation jar -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
                    <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/client/**</include>
                <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Here is my annotation processing config:
[image]

And, eventually, this is the error I get:

```
SEVERE: Server Error 500 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2><pre>javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/gwtRequest</p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReflectiveServiceLayer.<clinit>(ReflectiveServiceLayer.java:60)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayer.create(ServiceLayer.java:75)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.<init>(RequestFactoryServlet.java:103)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.<init>(RequestFactoryServlet.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:531)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    ... 31 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:531)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReflectiveServiceLayer.<clinit>(ReflectiveServiceLayer.java:60)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayer.create(ServiceLayer.java:75)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.<init>(RequestFactoryServlet.java:103)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.<init>(RequestFactoryServlet.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
</pre>
<p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>

ERROR: Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Server Error 500 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2><pre>javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/gwtRequest</p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReflectiveServiceLayer.<clinit>(ReflectiveServiceLayer.java:60)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayer.create(ServiceLayer.java:75)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.<init>(RequestFactoryServlet.java:103)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.<init>(RequestFactoryServlet.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:531)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    ... 31 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
```

I would be really thankful if someone could help me get through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally solved it.**

It seems I was all wrong about the problem. Indeed, my problem was related to maven config in pom.xml for bean validation. I was using a version of hibernate which is too recent, just had to downgrade to hibernate 4.3.1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730329/jpa-2-0-exception-to-use-javax-validation-package-in-jpa-2-0