# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I write small hibernate application and get following stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at com.beingjavaguys.hbn.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at com.beingjavaguys.hbn.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at crud.UserDao.addUser(UserDao.java:12)
    at com.beingjavaguys.hbn.App.main(App.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
...
```

I don't understand the reason of this mistake.

code:

```
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry); // exception thrown here
```

my pom.xml:

```
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         ...
     ...
```

I have read related topics but I really don't understand how to fix it - I don't want to roll out to hibernate 4.0 version.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Hibernate Validator 5x is not compatible with validation-api 1.0.x

[JPA 2.0 : Exception to use javax.validation.* package in JPA 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730329/jpa-2-0-exception-to-use-javax-validation-package-in-jpa-2-0)

Comment: can we use Hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar with validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar ?

Comment: When using Hibernate Validator 5.x, upgrade javax.validation to 2.x - this resolved it for me.

Comment: Hibernate-Validator 5.x uses the validation-api 1.1
From Hibernate-Validator 6, it uses the validation-api 2.0

Comment: BTW, in my case, downgrading all Hibernate Validator from v6.x to v5.x works well with validation-api 1.0.x. Thank you for the thinking direction!

Answer (score 57):

Just remove the javax.validation dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

That fixed this particular problem on my end.