# Bean Validation does't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm currently learning spring but I'm stuck with the validation annotation that don't works with my bean. I really don't understand what missing and I would need a Hand :)

I have a controller :

```
@Controller
public class CirclesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createCircle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createCircle(@Valid Circle circle, BindingResult res) {

        if (res.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Can't validate this form..");
        else
            System.out.println("Created new circle : " + circle);
    }
}
```

And a bean :

```
public class Circle {

    @Size(min = 5)                 // This is what I try to validate
    private String      name;

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I configured the web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:conf/dao-context.xml
        classpath:conf/services-context.xml
        classpath:conf/beans-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

my prject looks like that :

[image: Project]

the *-context.xml have the component-scan and anotation-config tags :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.app.[package-name]">
</context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<tx:annotation-driven></tx:annotation-driven>
```

I have all the external libraries (hibernate, hibernate-api, javax.validation) and no error on the run time...
but when I fill the field "name" wit less than 5 characters, I always get "Created new circle : Circle{name=txt}" instead of "Can't validate this form..".

EDIT :

Here is my classpath :

[image: classpath]

and the servlet-context.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.app.controllers"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Circle{name=NomDuCercle}  where does this name come from. That is more than 5 chars!

Comment: stupid me, I wrotte a bad exemple ! I update this question ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Providing the list of your dependencies and the *circles-servlet.xml* would give a full context to your question.

Nevertheless, for what I see there could be only two things missing. First make sure that you have the validation provider such as `hibernate-validator` on your classpath, second make sure that you have

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

element in your *circles-servlet.xml* it provides support for enabling validation against parameter objects of your controller annotated with *@Valid*

UPDATE after comment

the bean validation has an updated specification, so you should align your dependencies in the following manner

```
hibernate-validator-5.x.x 
validation-api-1.1.x
```

which will implement a JSR-349

OR

```
hibernate-validator-4.x.x
validation-api-1.0.x.
```

which implements JSR-303

Your issue from the comment means that you've most likely mixed the dependency, so used hibernate-validator-5.x.x with validation-api-1.0.x or missed it the other way around

Comment: thank you for your propsotion, I added this dependencie with maven and then in WEB-INF/lib and I got this error : SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider, any idea? Thank you very much !

Comment: See here: Dependency mismatch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652753/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-validation-parameternameprovider

Comment: exactly my point, vote up (vote up for you, not to be mistaken :) )

Comment: Bingo ! It works ! The tutorial I follow don't mention this dependencie, thanks to you @AlanHay too :) Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

See the very bottom of this page:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Add the following to you spring config:

```
<!-- JSR-303/JSR-349 support will be detected on classpath and enabled automatically -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: thank you but it still does not work :S I think the <tx:annotation-driven></tx:annotation-driven> works the same ..

Comment: <tx:annotation-driven> concerns transactions and has nothing to do with this. As advised in the other answer make sure you have a validation provider on the classpath.

Comment: yes true, I forgot why I had this tx:annotation-driven ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use @RequestBody annotation with @Valid annotation

```
public ModelAndView createCircle(@Valid @RequestBody Circle circle, BindingResult res) {
```

Comment: It's work fine for me along with <mvc:annotation-driven /> line in spring context file.