# Grails 2.4.4 with Hibernate can not find ValidatorFactory class

Tags: grails

having fougth with "ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory" exception, I created the fresh new 2.4.4 application with minimal functionality. Yes, I've read about [hibernate-validator-5.x.x and validation-api-1.0.x incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142416/3580266) and [2.4.4 Release Notes](https://grails.org/wiki/2.4.4%20Release%20Notes) and added dependecies to the validation-api:1.1.0 and hibernate-validator:5.0.3 to the BuildConfig.groovy as recommended, so finally it looks like following:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" 
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6

grails.project.fork = [
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
inherits("global") {
}
log "error" 
checksums true 
legacyResolve false 

repositories {
    inherits true 
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
    runtime 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final'
}

plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" 
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
 }
}
```

After it I added very simple hibernate-based domain class (code skipped for brewity), wrote mapping for it into hibernate.cfg.xml and did create-controller and run-app. And voila: "ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory". 
I tried to upgrade hibernate-validator to 5.1.3 and downgrade it to 4.3.1 (downgrading validation-api to 1.0.0 in the same time) and to downgrade hibernate to 4.3.5.5, but still no luck. What else can be done?
Full error dump below:

```
 Error 2015-03-17 11:31:47,191 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
->> 2531 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   2774 | getMethod0 in     ''
|   1663 | getMethod in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    358 | loadClass in     ''
|   2531 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
|   2774 | getMethod0 in     ''
|   1663 | getMethod in     ''
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

UPDATE: Strange enough, but  'run-war' does work without error, 'run-app' does not.

Comment: since you are also using the hibernate plugin, i doubt you need to reference the validator explicitly (if you don't care for versions). but this might not be the problem causing this.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's not the reason. I tried to comment off hibernate-validator depencency, but it did not help