# Maven - Suppress Overriding managed version warning in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, m2eclipse

I am using `spring-boot`, and experienced an error similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14730329/2860319).  I added the following to my pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am overriding the validation-api 1.0.0 dependency defined in my parent pom.xml, by way of Spring boot, and this gives the pesky warning message:

> Overriding managed version 1.0.0.GA for validation-api

How can I permanently suppress this warning message in Eclipse?  It shows up both in my pom.xml and my problems view.

Comment: Update the version in the given parent pom.

Comment: Adding the comment <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$--> works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  RE update the parent pom... I don't own the parent pom, it's inherited via Spring Boot.  RE adding <!-- NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ --> that didn't work either, but I don't know if I used it correctly.  I would also like to know more about it if that does clear out the warning.

Comment: If you are using spring-boot, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35385268/1568658

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When that warning shows up, you can open the Quick-Fix menu on the warning (Ctrl+1) and select

> Ignore this warning

This will add the  comment on the version line, like :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```

Your problem is you manually added that comment on the wrong line.

Comment: this worked for removing warning shown in eclipse but I am still unable to build the project. getting the error: `Rule 0: org.commonjava.maven.enforcer.rule.EnforceManagedDepsRule failed with message:The following 2 dependencies are NOT using a managed version`

Comment: This is a bad way to solve the issue, because it might broken the dependency of other library.

Answer (score 38):

Since the project is using `spring-boot`, a more proper answer could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385268/1568658

*(And since I got the same issue, and the above answer also is not very complete. I would add an answer here.)*

**Reason of issue:**

`spring-boot` has defined many dependencies & their versions, when you use `spring-boot` as parent, these dependencies got inherited, and overriding one of the dependency with a different version would get the warning, because it might break other libraries' dependencies.

**Solution:**

Define a property for that dependency between `<properties></properties>`, to specify the version.

e.g

```
        <properties>
            <reactor.version>2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</reactor.version>
        </properties>
```

**How to find the  property name:**

- Open your `pom.xml` in IDEA or Eclipse.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the `<parent>` tag to open pom of parent, and need to click twice recursively to finally get to the pom file with artifactId as `spring-boot-dependencies`.
- Once you have opened that pom, search for your dependency, e.g `servlet-api`, and you can see the default version.

There is a document from spring explains it better: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

Comment: I got it that this dependency was already defined in pom of spring parent. I also got the issue while including `mysql-connector-j` in my application. Does that mean spring will include the depency even though i do not need `mysql-connector-j` just because it is defined in parent pom?

Answer (score 5):

Enter version that you need in main pom.

This warning means that you are trying to override artifact version that is defined in your main (top level) pom. Just enter version that you need in main pom and you don't even need to use `<version />` in other poms for this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is with lombok.jar version. I do have multiple lombok versions and eclipse somehow taking a version but it detected more versions so unable to pick it's version. So I went to maven folder (.m2) and deleted the extra versions of lombok, did maven update on project, error gone.

But I haven't provided lombok version anywhere, eclipse choose a version, don't know how.

Answer (score -3):

useful ! I resolve the problem. As the module pom file declare 9.2.12.M0 while the spring-boot refer to the V9.3 . I overwrite the V9.2 in the parent pom file. follow by "Eric Wang"

Comment: spring-boot use the the default version,which is may be declared in the pom file as the element <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement> ,you should declare your own version to overwrite the default version.