# java.lang.ArrayStoreException in E2E Test caused by custom Constraint Annotation with Custom Validation Group

Tags: java, reflection, jackson, jersey-2.0, bean-validation

I'm writing an E2E Test for my REST-Application. So the test, that is located in the frontend, calls the deployed backend, this is working perfectly fine except for one tiny problem:
When the `readEntity` Method on the received `Response` is called, an `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` occurs. My observations show that the Problem lies within a self written Constraint Annotation:

I've written my own Constraint-Annotation `@Future` for Bean-Validation, my POJO uses this Annotation to validate that a `LocalDateTime` is in the future. I've also provided two simple Interfaces, which are used as Validation-Groups:

```
public interface ExistingInstance extends Default {

}
```

and

```
public interface NewInstance extends Default {

}
```

When i use one of these Interfaces as a validation group in my custom Constraint Annotation like follows:

```
public class Book {

   @Future(groups=NewInstance.class)
   private LocalDateTime validFrom;

   private LocalDateTime validTo;

   // Getters & Setters...
}
```

I receive this Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:543)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:367)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:84)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotationsFromCache(AccessibleObject.java:313)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1160)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:86)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:48)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:493)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:421)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:386)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:233)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._findCreatorsFromProperties(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:328)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:272)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:261)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:150)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:188)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:765)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:535)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._prefetchRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:2340)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(ObjectReader.java:723)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:804)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:885)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:845)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$2.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:101)
    at my.package.structure.books.BooksClient.readEntityFromResponse(BooksClient.java:309)
    at my.package.structure.books.BooksClient.getBooks(BooksClient.java:95)
    at my.package.structure.books.BooksClientTest.getBooks_Test(BooksClientTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$251.00000000126A8D40.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$143.000000001120E090.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$146.000000001148A600.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:186)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:127)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:523)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:162)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:185)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:245)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:429)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$143.000000001120E090.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$146.000000001148A600.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:186)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:127)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:523)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:162)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:185)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:245)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:429)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$143.000000001120E090.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Now the Confusing Part:

If i use my Validation-Group Interfaces on an Existing Annotation, provided by Java, like `@NotNull`:

```java
public class Book {
   
   @NotNull(groups=NewInstance.class)
   private LocalDateTime validFrom;

   private LocalDateTime validTo;

   // Getters & Setters...
}
```

It works like perfectly fine. Even if i use a class provided in the JDK, like `Default.class` as a group on my Custom Annotation:

```
public class Book {
   
   @NotNull(groups=Default.class)
   private LocalDateTime validFrom;

   private LocalDateTime validTo;

   // Getters & Setters...
}
```

It works!

What am i missing?

I use:

- Java v8
- JavaEE v7
- Jersey Client v2.33
- Jersey HK2 v2.33
- Hibernate Validator v5.4.3

**Note: I know that the Annotation `@Future` is already provided, but in Java 8 with JavaEE 7 it does not support the 'new' Time-API.**

*Edit*
Here is my code to reproduce the error:

Server-Side:
Wrapper for Returned Entities

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
   
   private T returnValue;
   private String exception;
   private Integer processingState;
   private String processingMessage;

   //Getter & Setter
}
```

```
@Path("books")
public class BookService {

   @EJB
   private BookRepo repository;

   @Path("all")
   public Response getAllBooks() {
      Response response = null;
      try {
         // findAll returns a List wrapped inside the above shown Wrapper class
         response = Response.status(200).entity(new GenericEntity<Wrapper<List<Book>>>(repository.findAll()){}).build();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         response = Response.status(500).build();
      }

      return response;
   }

}
```

Client Side:

```
public class BooksClient {

   private ObjectMapper mapper;
   private Client client;
   private WebTarget baseTarget;
   
   public BooksClient(String endpointAdress) {
      this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      this.mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
      this.mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

      JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(this.mapper);

      this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig().register(provider));

      this.baseTarget = this.client.target(endpointAdress);
   }

   public Wrapper<List<Book>> getBooks() {
      WebTarget bookTarget = baseTarget.path("all");
      
      Response response = bookTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

      return this.readEntityFromResponse(response);

   }

   private Wrapper<List<Book>> readEntityFromResponse(Response response) {
      Wrapper<List<Book>> result = null;

      GenericType<List<Book>> responseType = new GenericType<Wrapper<List<Book>>>(){};

      result = response.readEntity(responseType); // <--- root of Exception

      return result;
   }

}
```

Test Class

```
public class BooksClientTest {

   @Spy
   private BooksClient client = new BooksClient("http://localhost:1234/ws/books");

   @Test
   public void getBooks_Test() {
      Wrapper<List<Book>> result = this.client.getBooks();
      assertThat(result).isNotNull();
   }

}
```

Custom-Annotation:

```
/**
 * Validates a Time Value.
 */
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { FutureLocalDateTimeValidator.class, FutureLocalDateValidator.class,
    FutureLocalTimeValidator.class, FutureZonedDateTimeValidator.class })
public @interface Future {

  String message() default "Error while validating the date!";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Corresponding Validator:

```
public class FutureLocalDateTimeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Future, LocalDateTime> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(Future constraintAnnotation) {
    // not needed.
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(LocalDateTime value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
      return true;
    }

    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();
    return value.isAfter(today);
  }

}
```

I've tried different self written Annotations with the exact same result.

The Application is deployed on a WAS 9.0

If i use the actual frontend no error occurs.

Hope this helps, thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you could reproduce the error at a lower level by calling `Field#getDeclaredAnnotations()` on that particular field. If you want to allow others to be able to reproduce it, you should post all the necessary code.

Comment: You're still missing the custom annotation and validator to go with it. That was what I was referring to in the previous comment.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I will update my Post!

Comment: Do you know how to use reflection? I tried to reproduce the problem just using reflection and calling Field#getDeclaredAnnotations() on the field, as I mentioned, and I cannot reproduce the problem. I was wondering if you could reproduce it on your side simple using reflection (based on the stack trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm using

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

these are incompatible according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142416/10329676). 
I upgraded the version to:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And now everything works fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I could not find the exact version (the line numbers do not match), but [the code found on docjar.com](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/reflect/annotation/AnnotationParser.java.html) is plausible enough to explain what happens.

```java
private static Object parseClassArray(int length,
                                      ByteBuffer buf,
                                      ConstantPool constPool,
                                      Class<?> container) {
    Object[] result = new Class<?>[length];
    boolean typeMismatch = false;
    int tag = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        tag = buf.get();
        if (tag == 'c') {
            result[i] = parseClassValue(buf, constPool, container);
        } else {
            skipMemberValue(tag, buf);
            typeMismatch = true;
        }
    }
    return typeMismatch ? exceptionProxy(tag) : result;
}
```

```java
private static Object parseClassValue(ByteBuffer buf,
                                      ConstantPool constPool,
                                      Class<?> container) {
    int classIndex = buf.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
    try {
        try {
            String sig = constPool.getUTF8At(classIndex);
            return parseSig(sig, container);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            // support obsolete early jsr175 format class files
            return constPool.getClassAt(classIndex);
        }
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        return new TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy("[unknown]", e);
    }
    catch (TypeNotPresentException e) {
        return new TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy(e.typeName(), e.getCause());
    }
}
```

The interesting aspect is that the method `parseClassValue` does not always return a `Class<?>`; when a `NoClassDefFoundError` or `TypeNotPresentException` occurs, it will return a `TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy` instance instead.

Since `parseClassArray` does not check for this special return value but unconditionally stores the result into a `Class<?>[]` array, an `ArrayStoreException`  may occur.

This is a bug, obviously, but it also provides a hint why you are not always encountering this specific problem (and apparently, not many developers in general).

It only occurs when an *absent* type is referenced in an annotation value that has an array of `Class` type. So you may focus on the question which type is not available in the failing environment. One way to check this, is to enforce an earlier termination in the erroneous case, e.g.

```java
public class Book {
    // now, it will fail at class initialization time if the type is missing
   static final Class<?> DUMMY = NewInstance.class;

   @Future(groups=NewInstance.class)
   private LocalDateTime validFrom;

   private LocalDateTime validTo;

   // Getters & Setters...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
I added that line of code and now the Error says: 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.validation.groups.Default`
(Can't post the whole stacktrace