# how to set up hibernate validator 6.0.10.Final correctly

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I was trying to set up annotation validator to validate the object without using validator class. At first I only include the library validator-api 2.0.1.Final and everything seem to work fine but the object cannot be validated.

After doing some research, I found out that I need to add:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

to dispatcher servlet but this is when I got very headache. After that it come out an error

then, I added the latest version of hibernate validator to the project and this error come out.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
```

Trying to solve the error I have tried to add and remove different library and thing and changing the version of the library as well. I end up have these library in my project and I am not using maven to handle the dependency which make me harder to find the error. This is the library I have in my project:

[image: library for hibernate validator]

I used few hours to change the library and this is the final result I think might work but it doesn't. Did I miss out something important?

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addStaff(@Valid @ModelAttribute Staff staff,
        BindingResult result,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return new ModelAndView(parentFolder + "addStaff", "staff", staff);
    }

    return new ModelAndView( parentFolder + "addStaff", "staff", new Staff());

}
```

My Form:

```
<div class="form-style">
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="id">Staff ID</form:label>
    <form:input path="id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0123"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Adam Teh"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="email">Email</form:label>
    <form:input path="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="adam@example.com"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="tel">Tel No</form:label>
    <form:input path="tel" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="0171234567"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="role">Role</form:label>
    <form:select path="role" class="form-control">
        <form:option value="staff" label="staff" />
        <form:option value="admin" label="admin" />
    </form:select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Status</label>
    <div class="form-check">
        <form:radiobutton path="status" class="form-check-input" id="active" value="1" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="active">active</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <form:radiobutton path="status" class="form-check-input" id="inactive" value="0"/>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inactive">inactive</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Modal:

```
public class Staff {

@NotBlank(message = "Staff id cannot be empty.")
private String id;

@NotBlank(message = "Please type in your name")
private String name;

@Email(message = "There is problem with the email format.")
private String email;

@NotBlank(message = "Please key in your phone number")
@Pattern(message = "Please make sure your phone number only have 10 to 11 number only.", regexp = "^\\d{10,11}$")
private String tel;


private Role role;

private Department department;

private boolean status;

public Staff(String id, String name, String email, String tel, Role role, Department department, boolean status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.role = role;
    this.department = department;
    this.status = status;
}

public Staff() {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getTel() {
    return tel;
}

public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}}
```

My Log

```
29-Jun-2018 09:01:48.460 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
29-Jun-2018 09:01:48.996 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:296)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 36 more

29-Jun-2018 09:01:48.996 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet dispatcher
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:296)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Update:

After research for a while I found similar question on [nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764240/nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o)

I changed my library to
[image: Library List]

but another error seem to occur:

```
29-Jun-2018 13:06:04.616 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
29-Jun-2018 13:06:05.068 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 36 more

29-Jun-2018 13:06:05.068 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet dispatcher
 javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I thought that it might be the problem with class path but adding extra directory to the class path doesn't seem to work at all. I don't know what I miss in there.

[image: ClassPath listing]

---

Comment: Are u using `Maven`? Could u add the `pom` file?

Comment: No, I am not. After follow the question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764240/nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o.

Comment: The error changed to org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and trying for few hours, I finally got my problem solved. It turn out that there is some library I am missing that causes the error of NoClassDefFoundError.

This is the list of library I used in the project:

1. hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar
2. hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-6.0.10.Final.jar
3. hibernate-validator-cdi-6.0.10.Final.jar
4. validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
5. javax.el-3.0.1-b09.jar
6. classmate-1.4.0.jar
7. jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar

by referring to 
[nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764240/nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o)

After solving this issue, another error pop up, NoProviderFoundException.
This is cause by the line of code

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

I added to my dispatcher servlet. After some troubleshooting, I found a solution on 
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1495 having someone mentioning the old group id problem. I tried to check my library group id and found

> org.hibernate

but the new group id is

> org.hibernate.validator

Therefore, I change the my library to the correct group id and everything work fine.
and I also removed the line of code I added to my dispatcher-servlet because the problem is still there. Even I remove it, the program still able to run.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to remove `javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar`? The other jar already contains the API and the implementation and can lead to conflicts.

Comment: It is not working, may I ask how can I check if a library have conflict with each other?